# Prove that the following function is continuous at $0$

Tags: continuity

> Prove that the following function is **continuous at $0$**
>   $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(3x)}{\tan(2x)} \qquad \text{if} \ x<0 \ ; \\ \\
> \frac{3}{2} \qquad\quad\qquad \text{if} \ x=0 \ ; \\ \\
> \frac{\log(1+3x)}{e^{2x}-1} \ \ \ \text{if} \ x>0 \ .
> \end{cases}
> $$

How do I solve this problem?

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{3x} = 1 $
and $\displaystyle\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2x}=\log_ee$ .

Hope this will help.

Comment: Are you going to post all of your continuity-homework here?

Comment: This isnt my homework. I am just asking my doubts. This is my summer vacation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints (really the same hint twice):

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(3x)}{\tan(2x)}=\frac{\sin(3x)}{x}\frac{x}{\tan(2x)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\log(1+3x)}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{\log(1+3x)}{x}\frac{x}{3^{2x}-1}$

Extra bonus hint:

$\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$

Comment: I got the last one but not the first one. Can u elaborate +1

Answer (score 0):

It is not.  $\tan(-2 \pi)=0$ so $f(x)$ is not even defined at $x=-\pi$

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to mention "at 0"

Comment: @chndn: so take the limit of the values for $x$ approaching $0$ from below and show they approach $\frac 32$ and again from above.  Where are you having trouble?  You could look at the Taylor series.  Your statement that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{1+3x} = 1$ is not correct.  The numerator goes to zero and the denominator goes to 1, so the limit is $0$

Comment: How do I get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin3x}{tan2x} = \frac{3}{2}$? and question edited. thanks...+1

Comment: @chndn: I use the small angle approximation $\sin x = \tan x =x$ for $x \ll 1$ but I am a physicist/engineer.  I don't know if that is OK for you.

Comment: I didnt quite understand your observation. I want to solve it in mathematical steps( or something like that)

Comment: You have changed the limit you cite.  The earlier one does what I said before.  Now your statement is correct. user73324 has given some more explicit hints.  Can you use them?

Comment: yah , i got the second one. I couldnt get the first

Comment: Do you know $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin x}x=1$?  Then use L'Hopital or the chain rule or multiple angle identities.

Comment: I would be curious about the reason for the downvote.  When I posted it just asked about why $f(x)$ was not continuous-it didn't specify "at $0$".  My answer shows why it is not.

Comment: how do I solve $\frac{3x}{tan2x}$ and I had upvoted

Comment: @chndn:  As I said before, you can use multiple angle identities if you don't have other tools.  Expand $\tan 2x$ and recognize that $\cos x$ goes to $1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: what is the identity

Comment: The usual one is $\tan 2x=\frac {2 \tan x}{1-\tan^2 }$

Comment: How can I use it here? can you solve it for me?

Comment: Please give it some thought.

Comment: I didnt get it. whatever I do i cant make it 3/2

Comment: $\sin 3x \approx 3x, \tan 2x =\cos 2x \sin 2x \approx 1 \cdot 2x$

Comment: okay got it thanks